# SQL Server 2016 remote access denied

Tags: sql-server, remote-access, remote

I have two VM with an SQL server on each and I need to connect to both SQL servers from each machine, either from SSMS and with PowerShell script.
Also, today I don't manage to do that I'm always getting "Access Denied" from both server when trying to connect to the remote one.
[image: SQL server access Denied]

- Here is my setup.

  - Windows Server 2012 R2
  - Sql Server 2016 Dev edition
  - SSMS v18.2
  - Both machines are in the AD Domain,
  - I'm using on both machine my AD account which is member of the local Admin group of each server
  - The access to Administrative shares is working properly.
  - My account is member of the sysadmin Server Roles of both SQL server, and owner of the DB I need to reach.
  - Both server have the "Allow remote connections to this server" checked.
  - Both SQL server service are running under my AD account.
  - Both Server have the Firewall disable to make sure this is not due to Firewall restriction.

Any idea what I'm missing ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are the appropriate protocols enabled in SQL Configuration Manager? My guess is they're not. Check that first.

Comment: That exactly what I just find out 2mins ago ! Thanks for the prompt answer !

Comment: Developer Edition and Express Edition ship with IP connectivity disabled by default, as they are often installed on developer desktops and accessed only locally.